# AppleScript dialog and repeated `say' command not working in OS X cronjob

Tags: scripting, osx, cron

I've got a script in OS X that looks in a given directory for the file with the most recent mtime, sees if it's (past) a certain size, and, if so, creates an AppleScript dialog box + repeats an invocation of the `say` command until the dialog box is closed. I've verified that this script works for any given directory including the directory that I'm interested in. However, it only seems to work properly when I run it from an interactive shell (i.e., via zsh in Terminal.app, xterm, etc. or Eshell in Emacs). See, when I run the script as a cronjob, all it does is run the `say` invocation in the script once; no dialog box and no repetition of `say` until the box is closed, which is what I'm expecting it to do. However, I'm not getting any error messages in my `mail`, so it seems that `cron` thinks everything is going alright.

The way that I've got the cronjob set up is like so:

```
SHELL=/bin/zsh
*/1 * * * * . $HOME/.zshrc && ps caux | grep -iq my_script && : || $HOME/bin/my_script /some/dir
```

Translation: it runs every minute, first sourcing `~/.zshrc` (to set environment variables like `$PATH` et al.). Then it runs `ps caux`, grepping for my script's process name, and if a match is found then no-op. Otherwise, run my script, targeting `/some/dir`. The check to see if my process is running is done to make sure no overlapping instances of it occur and I've also verified that this works correctly.

So, when I run the code for that cronjob in a terminal, it works fine. However, as explained previously, something is causing the cronjob itself to not run as expected. When I consulted google about this sort of issue, I found [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12771333/2636454) that seems to mirror my problem, but for Linux. I tried the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12771422/2636454) there, which states to try launching the job via `xterm`. I.e.:

```
*/1 * * * * . $HOME/.zshrc && xterm -e ps caux | grep -iq my_script && : || $HOME/bin/my_script /some/dir
```

Yet, this was to no avail. Again, running the code for this cronjob via an interactive shell worked as expected, but `cron` itself still ran the script quirkily, with the only difference being that an `xterm` window appeared for a split second every minute.

I'm confused as to why this is happening and I'd like for the script to work as it does when run from an interactive shell. How can I accomplish this and why is `cron` running the script in an unexpected way?

Comment: `pgrep` is usually superior to `ps | grep`; if you stick with `ps | grep` at least use the `ps caux | grep -iq 'my_scrip[t]'` form to avoid the matches itself problem.

Comment: @thrig Ok, thanks for the advice. Strangely, I didn't have the "matches itself" problem when I tested this out with `ps caux`, although said problem happen with `ps aux`. Not exactly sure why that is. EDIT: Oh, I just realized that `caux` limits the column output to just contain the executable name, rather than the full command. So I guess "matches itself" wouldn't happen there because it would have to match the `grep` process, which is the actual executable that's running.

Comment: Still problematical, as shell scripts can run as "/bin/sh /path/to/script" in which case `ps c` will only see the `/bin/sh` bit and not the desired `script` name. `pgrep -f my_script` should better find it.

Comment: @thrig Yes, that's true. However, my script isn't a *shell* script; it's built with the [Racket](https://racket-lang.org) language. Right now, this is the only `racket` process which is running on the machine in question so I don't need to worry about other `racket` processes doing things like that. I.e., I'm actually grepping for the `racket` interpreter, not the script name, so it's working fine for me. I just put in the question that I'm grepping for the script name since I didn't want to add unnecessary details. Thanks again for the advice, though.

Comment: Hmm, `* * * * * /usr/bin/osascript -e 'display dialog "hello"'` doesn't show anything for me. Perhaps instead hand the notifications off to something like growl instead? http://growl.info

Comment: @thrig Oh yeah, I forgot; I tried a cronjob just like that as well. It didn't show anything for me either. Thanks for the suggestion; I'll look into that.